# Regex to remove the company type from the name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am pretty new to Regex and am trying to learn.

I am creating a mail merge tool and would like to use `RegExp` to give me more flexibility and control. One of the placeholders that I replace is `company_name`.

I have a list of companies. Many have the company type in their name (e.g. My Company **, Inc.**, or My Company **LLC**). I would like to use regex to standardize the results. However, I am not sure how to write it, other than to manually list each and every option. For example, each of these names should result in the same value at the end:

- My Company LLC
- My Company, LLC
- My Company, Inc.
- My Company, Inc
- MY Company Inc.
- My Company Inc
- My Company Co
- My Company

And on and on...

I believe I can use this to achieve my desired results:

```
var companyName = lead.company_name;
companyName = companyName.replace(/(, Inc.)|( Inc.)|(, LLC)/gi, '');
```

However, I was hoping there is a more efficient way to:

1. Capture the variations
2. Ensure the company type is always at the end
3. Include commas and periods if they exist, but not have to list all options with and without

CAUTION:
I have to account for the possibility of the company type characters existing in the actual name (e.g. My `Co`mpany `Co`) and only remove the organization type at the end.

Can this be done easily?

Comment: "_CAUTION: I have to account for the possibility of the company type characters existing in the actual name_" does that mean that if those characters exist in the actual name, they should (or should not) be removed?

Comment: Generally, for example, "Company, LLC" *is* the company name. If you remove "LLC", you're no longer using the correct name.

Comment: @Ouroborus, you are correct, but no one would type the full company name (with company type) in the body of an email so it would be obvious that it is a generated email, or require extra manipulation to clean it up before sending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If each company name is a string on its own, you can try the following regex:

`/,?\s*(llc|inc|co)\.?$/i`

Explanation:

- Optional comma
- Optional whitespace
- Either one of LLC/Inc/Co (case-insensitive)
- Optional period
- All the above at the end of the string

```js
const companyNames = [
'My Company LLC',
'My Company, LLC',
'My Company, Inc.',
'My Company, Inc',
'MY Company Inc.',
'My Company Inc',
'My Company Co',
'My Company',
];

console.log(companyNames.map(name => name.replace(/,?\s*(llc|inc|co)\.?$/i, '')));
```

Comment: is there any way to remove `private limited` or `pvt ltd` or `pvt. ltd.` using this regex?

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU of course there is, you just need to modify the regex

Comment: I am using this regex. Is it okay `/,?\s*(llc|inc|co|pvt|ltd|private|limited)\.?$/i`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a more efficient way (if by efficient we mean shorter), though multi-conditional patterns like this often lead to a trade-off between succinctness vs. readability.

It's a matter of sub-groups, which allows us to avoid repetition.

```
var rgx = /(, ?)?(LLC|Inc|Co)\.?$/i;
```

Let's break it down.

- The first part, `(, ?)?`, says the company name should be optionally followed by a combination of a comma and an optional space. So this would allow no comma, a comma with no space after it, or a comma with a space after it.
- The second part, `(LLC|Inc|Co)` is a simple sub-group allwing the different type suffixes
- The final part, `\.?`, allows for an optional period at the end (we escape the period because in most REGEX implementations the period has special meaning, matching any non-space character).

Note also you don't need the `g` flag, since (presumably) no company name will have more than one type suffix. Also, the `$` flag is useful here as it ensures our match must be at the end of the company name, not merely somewhere within it.

Comment: This converts `My Company, LLC` to `My Company,`

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation. However, the `(, ?)?` does not remove the `,` as expected. Otherwise, it works.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do:

```
companyName = companyName .replace(/,?\h*(?:\b(?:inc|LLC|co)\b\.?)?$/i,"");
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                       : delimiter
    ,?                  : optional comma
    \h*                 : optional horizontal spaces
    (?:                 : non capture group
        \b              : word boundary
        (?:inc|LLC|co)  : non capture group, one of the alternatives
        \b              : word boundary
        \.?             : a dot, optional
    )?                  : end group, optional
    $                   : end of string
/i                      : delimiter, case insensitive
```

Comment: Why? Can we get an explanation?

Comment: This converts `My Company, LLC` to `My mpany `

Comment: @davids: I've added word boundaries, to deal with that. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation. It definitely help me better understand RegEx. However, this still leaves the trailing `,` and spaces. `My Company, Inc` becomes `My Company, `